# TypeScript v2.3.1 breaks unit tests

Tags: typescript, phantomjs

I have been running my project using TS without issues for a couple of months now up to and including version 2.2.2. TypeScript 2.3 was recently released and I decided to update to the latest patch version (v2.3.2).

Unfortunately this is where my PhantomJS (running my tests) starts breaking. I also have Wallaby running which has no issues with this latest version and building & running my application seems to be working fine too.

I tried downgrading patch versions until it started working again and it seems that it starts breaking by upgrading from v2.3.0 to v2.3.1.
Comparing those two versions on [Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/compare/v2.3.0...v2.3.1) gives me way to many changes to scroll through and I can't seem to find the change log for this patch version update (not for the entire v2.3 version update which is listed [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/releases) as v2.3.0 is running fine). So I would really like to know what has changed (and preferably what has changed that could have impact on PhantomJS).

The PhantomJS error I get if anyone is interested:

```
START:
03 05 2017 09:34:54.160:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.6.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
03 05 2017 09:34:54.162:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
03 05 2017 09:34:54.167:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
03 05 2017 09:34:55.058:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket lYV_7fbawdBMHcp0AAAA with id 4050484
03 05 2017 09:35:05.061:WARN [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Disconnected (1 times), because no message in 10000 ms.
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 10000 ms.

Finished in 10.005 secs / 0 secs @ 09:35:05 GMT+0200 (CEST)

[09:35:05] 'test' errored after 12 s
[09:35:05] Error: Failed 1 tests.
    at karma.Server.failCount (.../build/tasks/test.js:15:26)
    at removeAllListeners (.../node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:380:7)
    at Server.<anonymous> (.../node_modules/karma/lib/server.js:391:9)
    at Server.g (events.js:286:16)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at Server.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at emitCloseNT (net.js:1549:8)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:71:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

*EDIT*
Ran a diff between the v2.3.0 transpiled sources and the v2.3.1 transpiled sources and the result was absolutely nothing.

*EDIT 2*
Just tried to run it using v2.3.3, but got the same result.

*EDIT 3*
Tried to use ChromeHeadless instead of PhantomJS and it fails the same way. Seems like PhantomJS was indeed not the issue here.

*EDIT 4*
Tried to use Karma 1.7.0. Still no change.

Comment: It seems like your test code fails which uses phantomjs + karma runner. I think It is not about phantomjs itself

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just checked the diff between the transpiled sources and there were no differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I switched from JSPM/SystemJS to Aurelia CLI to fix the issue. The switch was pretty easy and it now all seems to work with TypeScript 2.3.4.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the transpiled output for diff between the working and the non working.

Comment: Thanks, had not checked that yet. Just ran a diff between the v2.3.0 transpiled sources and the v2.3.1 transpiled sources and the result was absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue is happening also with TS 2.4.0.

I fixed it by switching to [plugin-typescript](https://github.com/frankwallis/plugin-typescript), which looks like the new offical way to transpile TS in SystemJS.